# With ArcGIS Server's REST API, can I request a non-default symbol size when requesting a legend JSON?

Tags: arcgis-server, legend, arcgis-rest-api

I am using the [ArcGIS Server REST API](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/rest/apiref/) to retrieve legend information for one of our map services. I am requesting that information as a JSON object, so my HTTP request URL looks like this:

```
http://<host>/ArcGIS/rest/services/<mapServiceName>/MapServer/legend?f=json
```

The legend symbol images I get back from this are all 20×20 pixels in size (which seems to be the default). Guessing from [the relevant bit of Esri's documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/rest/apiref/mslegend.html), there is no way to request a different symbol image size (e.g. larger images for high-resolution printing). That would, however, be possible using the SOAP API (I believe by specifying [`MapServerLegendPatch`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/soap/10.2/index.html#//01vp000000rr000000) objects).

Is there any way to request a different legend symbol image size using the REST API?